# Install Sylius - Symfony2 OpenSource Ecommerce

Tags: symfony, installation, e-commerce, sylius

I am trying to install Sylius from [here](http://sylius.com/get-started) but i am unable to get it working.
On running the command i get process timed out...well...due to the ever slow internet we use here.
Could anyone please guide into installing sylius manually??
Like say manually updating vendors using composer.phar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If composer timeouts try this:

```
$ COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=300 ./composer.phar install
```

You can replace 300 with any number of seconds you prefer.